# SQL string manipulation to add xml nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using sql 2008R2, The table is having xml column like-

```
<New>
   <From>
        <Scale>Tony</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
<New>
    <From>
        <Scale>Tom</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>

 <New>
    <From>
        <Scale>Seven</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
<New>
    <From>
        <Scale>Ten</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
<New>
    <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
   </From>
</New>
```

.......so on

I need to write a SQL which can check all the nodes where the ScaleName's         Scale is not havng ***XXX*** as value and then add/insert the following text, for 2 times. When there is only one ***XXX**** entry it should add/insert only one time

```
<New>
    <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Respective Scalename</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
```

EXPECTED RESULT -----

```
<New>
   <From>
        <Scale>Tony</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
    </From>

<New>
    <From>
        <Scale>Tom</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
<New>
   <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
<New>

   <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>


 <New>
    <From>
        <Scale>Seven</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
    </From>
 </New>
 <New>
    <From>
        <Scale>Ten</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
    </From>
 </New>
 <New>
    <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
   </From>
 </New>
 <New>
    <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>
```

Comment: *nd then add the text where it is not, for 2 times* - show how should look the expected result

Comment: Is your XML really without a root element (not impossible, but not best choice...)? And please explain, what you mean with *add/insert the following text, for 2 times*. I do not see any *following text* and where/why/what do you want to insert two times?  As @RomanPerekhrest asked already: Please provide the expected output and the code you have tried so far...

Comment: add/insert means adding XML codes. This code is required for a java basd app. XXX entries need to be 2 times for each unique scalename

Comment: XXX entries = <New>
    <From>
        <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
        <ScaleName>Respective Scalename</ScaleName>
    </From>
</New>

Comment: expected result under - EXPECTED RESULT -----

Comment: Please confirm if correct or explain again: There are distinct scalenames. Each group of scale values should have exactly two times the `***XXX***` entry with the given `ScaleName`. If one scale has got two of these, fine, if there's only one, add one, if there's none, add two. Might these elements include other values? If not, it was easiest to eliminate them completely and add two for each ScaleName no matter of existance...

Comment: Sure, scalename can be repetitive and different. True, I need to find scalename, check if they have <name> as ***XXX*** existing, if not then to add two, if 1 then to add just 1. values of elements doesn't matter. But the values of  <name> are dynamic. How to control through sql, need logic and some syntax please.

Comment: Okay, In this case my posted answer should be quite fitting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know whether I fully understood what you need, but this might help:

**attention**: It is - in most cases! - a **bad idea to work with *magic values* such as `***XXX***`...**

This is your example XML. The scale `Name` has no `***XXX***` entry and scale `height` has got one...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(N'<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Tony</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Tom</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Seven</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Ten</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>');
```

--The CTE reads the XML into a derived table ommiting the entries with `***XXX***`

```
WITH ScaleNames AS
(
    SELECT  fr.value('(Scale)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Scale
           ,fr.value('(ScaleName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ScaleName
    FROM @xml.nodes('/New/From') AS A(fr)
    WHERE fr.value('(Scale)[1]','nvarchar(100)')<>'***XXX***'
)
```

--This `SELECT` will rebuild the whole XML using the *real* values and adding two times the `***XXX***` nodes.

```
SELECT (
            SELECT x.Scale AS [From/Scale]
                  ,x.ScaleName AS [From/ScaleName]
            FROM ScaleNames AS x
            WHERE x.ScaleName=ScaleNames.ScaleName
            FOR XML PATH('New'),TYPE
       )
      ,(SELECT
        (SELECT '***XXX***' AS Scale, ScaleName FOR XML PATH('From'),ROOT('New'),TYPE )
        ,(SELECT '***XXX***' AS Scale, ScaleName FOR XML PATH('From'),ROOT('New'),TYPE )
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ) AS [node()]
FROM ScaleNames
GROUP BY ScaleName
FOR XML PATH('')
```

The result

```
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Seven</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Ten</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Height</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Tony</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>Tom</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
<New>
  <From>
    <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
    <ScaleName>Name</ScaleName>
  </From>
</New>
```

Comment: wow!!! thats supercool, I will check and update. regarding magic word, its a part of java frontend dropdown. Thank you so much.

Comment: by the way, is there any way to get it done by reading xml as string. just in case

Comment: @Priya, glad to help you! If you like this, it would be kind to tick the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. About reading the XML *as string*: As long as the string contains valid XML it is simply done by `DECLARE @xml XML=(SELECT CAST(@SomeValidXML AS XML))`. It is best to use a variable of type `NVARCHAR`, but make sure, that the XML does not start with a declaration with `utf-8`. If you've got the XML as literal, it is best to add a `N` in front of the string to get it `unicode` (DECLARE @myXML NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'some xml here')

Comment: I am new here, any possibility to share ur feedback or rating please

Comment: @Priya What do you mean with  *share ur feedback or rating* ?

Comment: @Priya Thx for the acceptance, this means 15 points to my account and 2 to yours. Once you've crossed the 15 points border you are allowed to vote (up and down). You might come back at this time... :-) I vote your question up, to give you a little push :-)

Comment: 1 additional help please..... the main xml is having other root node above <From> and <New>. and there are some more nodes within <From> (like </OtherName> <Units>Kilogram</Units>) which I have to copy as is. How to manage that

Comment: @Priya This does not sound like *1 additional little help* The whole approach is based on the idea to read the XML and re-build it. If there are other nodes and deeper structure, this might not work at all. Please start a new question with a clear example and the expected output. Then place a link to this new question here and I will pop up there soon.

Comment: here is the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40087952/edit-xml-column-using-sql-not-so-structured-xml

Comment: need your help desperately