# Edit XML column using SQL . Not so structured XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

#### This question is a [Follow-Up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40080985/5089204)

How to edit XML by getting new tags for '***XXX***', not so structured xml. Need help, I am very new to XML and XQuery. Have to get new tags (nodes) for X if it is none, in case of 1 need to insert 1 only. is there any way to manipulate string on larger scale

```
<NewAttributeRules>
<items>
<NewAttributeItem>
  <Scale>CAAA</Scale>
  <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
  <comment />
  <positiveRules>
    <NewAttributeRule type="POSITIVE">
      <conditions>
        <InCondition column="PPRD" colDataType="STRING">
          <values>
            <string>CAAAEXTENDED</string>
          </values>
        </InCondition>
      </conditions>
    </NewAttributeRule>
  </positiveRules>
  <negativeRules />
 </NewAttributeItem>


 <NewAttributeItem>
  <Scale>high TOTAL OTHERS</Scale>
  <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
  <comment />
  <positiveRules>
    <NewAttributeRule type="POSITIVE">
      <conditions>
        <InCondition column="ATC3" colDataType="STRING">
          <values>
            <string>B10787 EXT</string>
          </values>
        </InCondition>
      </conditions>
    </NewAttributeRule>
  </positiveRules>
  <negativeRules>
    <NewAttributeRule type="NEGATIVE">
      <conditions>
        <InCondition column="PPRD" colDataType="STRING">
          <values>
            <string>hkJKKK</string>
            <string>GAGHA</string>
            </values>
        </InCondition>
      </conditions>
    </NewAttributeRule>
    </negativeRules>
   </NewAttributeItem>
      

<NewAttributeItem>
  <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
  <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
  <comment />
  <positiveRules />
  <negativeRules />
</NewAttributeItem>
<NewAttributeItem>
  <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
  <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
  <comment />
  <positiveRules />
  <negativeRules />
 </NewAttributeItem>

<NewAttributeItem>
  <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
  <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
  <comment />
  <positiveRules />
  <negativeRules />
 </NewAttributeItem>
<NewAttributeItem>
  <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
  <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
  <comment />
  <positiveRules />
  <negativeRules />
 </NewAttributeItem>

</items>
</NewAttributeRules>
```

Comment: <NewAttributeRules> and   <NewAttributeRule> are two diff nodes

Comment: This XML is not valid... It is impossible to help you, if you do not provide the necessary input. Please try to reduce your XML to the nodes needed (in other words: Take away the elements which are similare / the same as others and can be fiddled into any solution easily) and make sure, that the XML provided can be set to a XML variable. And please add the expected output fitting to the provided input.

Comment: @Shnugo I have edited the code

Comment: Please, before you poste the next example, try this `DECLARE @xml  XML=N'Copy your xml here'; SELECT @xml;` If this is working, please click the XML-link (XML opens in extra window), `ctrl + a` then `tab` then `strg+c` and copy the whole formatted XML into your question. This XML is - again - not valid...

Comment: @Shnugo, Sorry for trouble, I have updated it correctly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now the XML is valid...

Together with the information form your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40080985/5089204) I'd suggest this approach:

I put your XML into a declared variable

```
declare @xml xml=
N'<NewAttributeRules>
  <items>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>CAAA</Scale>
      <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules>
        <NewAttributeRule type="POSITIVE">
          <conditions>
            <InCondition column="PPRD" colDataType="STRING">
              <values>
                <string>CAAAEXTENDED</string>
              </values>
            </InCondition>
          </conditions>
        </NewAttributeRule>
      </positiveRules>
      <negativeRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>high TOTAL OTHERS</Scale>
      <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules>
        <NewAttributeRule type="POSITIVE">
          <conditions>
            <InCondition column="ATC3" colDataType="STRING">
              <values>
                <string>B10787 EXT</string>
              </values>
            </InCondition>
          </conditions>
        </NewAttributeRule>
      </positiveRules>
      <negativeRules>
        <NewAttributeRule type="NEGATIVE">
          <conditions>
            <InCondition column="PPRD" colDataType="STRING">
              <values>
                <string>hkJKKK</string>
                <string>GAGHA</string>
              </values>
            </InCondition>
          </conditions>
        </NewAttributeRule>
      </negativeRules>
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativeRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativeRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativeRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativeRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
  </items>
</NewAttributeRules>';
```

--As before, the CTE will read the ScaleName for later grouping, but will let the whole node *as is*

```
WITH ScaleNames AS
(
    SELECT  ai.query('.') AS AiNode
           ,ai.value('(ScaleName)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ScaleName
    FROM @xml.nodes('/NewAttributeRules/items/NewAttributeItem') AS A(ai)
    WHERE ai.value('(Scale)[1]','nvarchar(100)')<>'***XXX***'
)
```

--This SELECT will rebuild the whole XML using the existing nodes and adding two times the ***XXX*** nodes.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT (
                SELECT x.AiNode AS [node()]
                FROM ScaleNames AS x
                WHERE x.ScaleName=ScaleNames.ScaleName
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
           ) AS [node()]
          ,(SELECT
             (SELECT '***XXX***' AS Scale, ScaleName, '' AS comment, '' AS positiveRules, '' AS negativRules FOR XML PATH('NewAttributeItem'),TYPE )
            ,(SELECT '***XXX***' AS Scale, ScaleName, '' AS comment, '' AS positiveRules, '' AS negativRules FOR XML PATH('NewAttributeItem'),TYPE)
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
           ) AS [node()]
    FROM ScaleNames
    GROUP BY ScaleName
    ORDER BY ScaleName
    FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('items'),TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('NewAttributeRules')
```

The result

```
<NewAttributeRules>
  <items>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>high TOTAL OTHERS</Scale>
      <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules>
        <NewAttributeRule type="POSITIVE">
          <conditions>
            <InCondition column="ATC3" colDataType="STRING">
              <values>
                <string>B10787 EXT</string>
              </values>
            </InCondition>
          </conditions>
        </NewAttributeRule>
      </positiveRules>
      <negativeRules>
        <NewAttributeRule type="NEGATIVE">
          <conditions>
            <InCondition column="PPRD" colDataType="STRING">
              <values>
                <string>hkJKKK</string>
                <string>GAGHA</string>
              </values>
            </InCondition>
          </conditions>
        </NewAttributeRule>
      </negativeRules>
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>b007</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>CAAA</Scale>
      <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules>
        <NewAttributeRule type="POSITIVE">
          <conditions>
            <InCondition column="PPRD" colDataType="STRING">
              <values>
                <string>CAAAEXTENDED</string>
              </values>
            </InCondition>
          </conditions>
        </NewAttributeRule>
      </positiveRules>
      <negativeRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
    <NewAttributeItem>
      <Scale>***XXX***</Scale>
      <ScaleName>OC07</ScaleName>
      <comment />
      <positiveRules />
      <negativRules />
    </NewAttributeItem>
  </items>
</NewAttributeRules>
```